# How to embed URL link to QLabel

Tags: python, qt, url, pyqt, qlabel

Clicking QLabel should open a default web browser with URL link specified. It is not happening yet. Why? 
A second question. Would it be possible to override the default blue color of the Label's font with something else?

[image]

```
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        vLayout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(vLayout)
        urlLink="<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">'Click this link to go to Google'</a>" 
        label=QtGui.QLabel(self)
        label.setText(urlLink)
        vLayout.addWidget(label)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The styling of the label's contents can be modified using the [standard html syntax](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html).

To automatically [open external links](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#openExternalLinks-prop):

```
    label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
```

Comment: Thanks Ekhumoro! Here it is colored black: `urlLink=" <a href=\"http://www.google.com\"> <font face=verdana size=12 color=black> This is a link</font> </a>" `

Comment: It should also be noted that `setTextInteractionFlags` must have `LinksAccessibleByMouse` set.  https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-5.15/PySide2/QtCore/Qt.html?highlight=textselectablebymouse#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.Qt.TextInteractionFlag

Answer (score 0):

In Qt Designer,

1. Ensure the label object containing the link is selected,
2. Locate the `openExternalLinks` property within the QLabel Group in the Property Editor (you can type `open` into the Property Editor filter field),
3. Set property `openExternalLinks` to True (checked). [This property is set to `False` by default.]

[image: Qt Designer Property Editor]